# How to skip a row from sort using MatSort?

Tags: angular, angular7, mat-table

I am aware that to use the sorting functionality of MatTable you use

```
mat-sort-header
```

But is there a way to skip a row when sorting?

[image]

Basically from the sample table above I just want to sort the data in row 1 - 3.

When I use the

```
mat-sort-header
```

it also includes the first row (highlighted in red) in the sorting. Can it be excluded from sorting? Thanks.

Here is the [**Snippet Link**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkz9yn)

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>       
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Column 1 </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="column1">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Column 2 </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.col1}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="column2">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Column 3 </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.col2}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="column3">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Column 4 </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.col3}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from '@angular/material';

export interface Data {
  name?: string,
  col1?: string,
  col2?: string,
  col3?: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  data: Array<Data> = [];
  columns: any[] = ['name', 'column1', 'column2', 'column3'];
  displayedColumns: any[] = [];

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Data>;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit() {
    for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
      this.data.push({
        name: "Row " + i,
        col1: "Data " + i,
        col2: "Data " + i,
        col3: "Data " + i
      });
    }

    this.data.unshift({
      name: '',
      col1: 'Data Summary 1',
      col2: 'Data Summary 2',
      col3: 'Data Summary 3'
    });

    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
    this.displayedColumns = this.displayedColumns.concat(this.columns);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of your table.

Comment: @Dino Added the snippet

Comment: You should post the relevant code here for a couple reasons. Links expire leaving post with no context for future users having similar problems. And, by not including the relevant content here, you are asking people to jump through an additional hoop in order to provide help.

Comment: @TheHeadRush Added the code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check my fix for your question

[Snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-areeg2)

use (matsortchange) and write your own requirements like how you want to sort your rows :)

html:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" matSortDisableClear  matSortDirection="asc">
```

ts:
//add another property sortable to your model as boolean as push it as false for the rows that you don't want to sort and push it as true for the rows that you want to sort

reason I have added cases is - for example if you have column1 data as the number then this solution won't work so you should not have to convert them into lowercase

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from '@angular/material';

export interface Data {
  name?: string,
  col1?: string,
  col2?: string,
  col3?: string,
  sortable?:boolean
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  data: Array<Data> = [];
  columns: any[] = ['name', 'column1', 'column2', 'column3'];
  displayedColumns: any[] = [];

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Data>;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit() {
    for(let i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
      this.data.push({
        name: "Row " + i,
        col1: "Data " + i,
        col2: "Data " + i,
        col3: "Data " + i,
        sortable:true
      });
    }

    this.data.unshift({
      name: '',
      col1: 'Data Summary 1',
      col2: 'Data Summary 2',
      col3: 'Data Summary 3',
      sortable:false
    });

    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);

    this.displayedColumns = this.displayedColumns.concat(this.columns);
  }
sortData(sort: MatSort): void {
        const data: Array<Data> = this.dataSource.data.slice();
        if (!sort.active || sort.direction === '') {
            this.dataSource.data = data;
            return;
        }

        this.dataSource.data = data.sort((a, b) => {
          if(!a.sortable || !b.sortable){
             return 1
          }
          else{
            let isAsc: boolean = sort.direction === 'asc';
            switch (sort.active) {
                case 'name': return this.compare(a.name.toLowerCase(), b.name.toLowerCase(), isAsc, );
                case 'column1': return this.compare(a.col1.toLowerCase(), b.col1.toLowerCase(), isAsc);
                 case 'column2': return this.compare(a.col2.toLowerCase(), b.col2.toLowerCase(), isAsc);
                  case 'column3': return this.compare(a.col3.toLowerCase(), b.col3.toLowerCase(), isAsc);
                default: return 0;
            }
        }}
        );
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Data>(this.dataSource.data);
    }
    compare(a: any, b: any, isAsc: boolean): number {
        if (a < b) {
            return -1 * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
        } else if (a > b) {
            return 1 * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
        } else {
            return 0 * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
        }
    }
  ngAfterViewInit() {

  }
}
```